# How get Conditional average on date in DataFraem?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mean

I have a data frame in which some rows are equal, first I want to subtract the larger date from the smaller date in the rows that are equal, and then finally calculate the average of the dates obtained, which is the average of a few days. But only select dates that have at least two Order_id with one Customer_id, My data frame looks like this:

```
Customer_id   date     Order_id
12          22/11/2021     2
12          29/11/2021     2
12          30/11/2021     2
42          10/11/2021     2
42          18/11/2021     2
43          19/11/2021     3
```

Then subtract the dates: (The last line was not selected because it has one customer_ID and one order_id)

```
Customer_id   date     Order_id  Subtract_date
12          22/11/2021     2         8
12          29/11/2021     2         8
12          30/11/2021     2         8
42          10/11/2021     2         8
42          18/11/2021     2         8
```

Then the duplicate rows are deleted and finally the average of the Subtract_date column is taken:

```
Customer_id   date     Order_id  Subtract_date
12          22/11/2021     2         8
42          10/11/2021     2         8
```

Comment: By "rows that are equal" you mean rows where `Customer_id` and `Order_id` are equal, but dates aren't, right?

Comment: yesو The Order_id column is the same in all rows but the Customer_id column is the same in some heads

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure if I understand. You consider rows `12          22/11/2021     2`  and `12          30/11/2021     2` equal, and rows `12          30/11/2021     2` and `42          10/11/2021     2         8` not equal, right?

Comment: In my dataframe, there are rows that have the same customer ID, and each customer ID has a different date in the date column. Among the dates for each customer ID, the largest date must be found and minus the smallest date to make a difference. For example, customer ID 12 has three dates, only the largest date is / 30/11/2021 and the smallest date is 11/22/2012, and the two are reduced and there is a difference in the subtract_id column .

Comment: In fact, columns that have the same customer ID are equal, for example, customer ID 12 has three rows that are equal but have different dates in the date column that I want to get the largest and smallest date for each customer ID and the difference To calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following to remove customers with 1 order:

```
cust_to_keep = df.groupby('Customer_id').date.transform('count')
df = df.loc[cust_to_keep>1]
```

and then leverage Groupby and NamedAggregation to get the desired output:

```
import datetime as dt
df.groupby(['Customer_id','Order_id']).agg(date=('date','min'),Subtract_date = ('date',lambda x:(x.max()-x.min()).days)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if I understand correct:

```
df.groupby(['Customer_id', 'oder_id']).agg(np.ptp).reset_index().rename({'date':'Subtract_date'}, axis = 1)
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: To filter the last row (or any with 0 days), use df[df["Subtract_date"] > 0]

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but my question is how to find the largest and smallest date for each customer ID and subtract them to get the difference? like customer ID 12